# An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code, C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

Im trying to work with databases and Entity-framework.

Here Is my Database:

[image: Database]

I have the following file that creates an context:

```
namespace SportsStore.domain.Concrete
{
    //Associate the model with the database
    //This class then automatically defines a property for each table in the database that I want to work with. 
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext { 


        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        /*protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }*/
    }
}
```

Here IS my file that Initialize the context-class:

```
namespace SportsStore.domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products.ToList(); } 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Failed to set database initializer of type 'SportsStore.domain.Concrete, EFProductRepository' for DbContext type 'SportsStore.domain.Concrete, EFDbContext' specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for details.

Here Is the details message of the inner exception:

> Can not load file or assembly EFDbContext or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file EFDbContext

Here Is my App.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      </configSections>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=SportsStore.domain.Concrete;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Here is my Web.Config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.web>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
      </system.codedom>
      <entityFramework>

        <contexts>
          <context type="SportsStore.domain.Concrete, EFDbContext">
            <databaseInitializer type="SportsStore.domain.Concrete, EFProductRepository" />
          </context>
        </contexts>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

How does it know which database to use?

I'm new to Entity framework and databases in .NET.

Comment: The explanation is in the exception that you get. Unfortunately, you have not included the important part with the actual description: _See inner exception for details._

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Check my updated question. :)

Comment: Try to read the exception message yourself. The new one you have provided also says _See inner exception for details._ You have to continue reading until you get to the root cause and then hopefully you will find the answer to your question or at least you can ask a bit more informed question here.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Sorry, I pasted the wroing one. Check again. I don't know how to solve It. I don't know why This error appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Web.config` file you have the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="SportsStore.domain.Concrete, EFDbContext">
        <databaseInitializer type="SportsStore.domain.Concrete, EFProductRepository" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here you specify that the assembly `EFDbContext` contains a context type `SportsStore.domain.Concrete` that should be initialized by initializer type `SportsStore.domain.Concrete` in assembly `EFProductRepository`.

Some of these names looks rather unorthodox. Combined with the underlying error that *The system can not find the file EFDbContext* my guess is that you need to go through this configuration and fix it.

- Do you have one or two assemblies? If only one then specify the correct name in the configuration.
- Are the context and the initializer specified by the correct type? If not correct the type names.
- Do you even have an initializer? If not remove the configuration completely from `Web.config`. `EFProductRepository` is certainly not an initializer.

You specify a type in a configuration file like this:

```
[Fully qualified name of type including namespace], [Name of assembly without .DLL]
```

So to specify you context assuming the assembly name is `EFDbContext` you write this:

```
SportsStore.domain.Concrete.EFDbContext, EFDbContext
```

The assembly name is probably wrong based on the error that you get but only you know the correct name.

Comment: The files EFDbContext.cs and EFProductRepository.cs are located In a folder called Concrete. The folder belongs to a project called SportsStore.domain.  What do you mean with an Initializer here?

Comment: @Bryan: In your `Web.config` file you have specified that your context should use a [database intializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606#Initializers) but if that is not your intention then remove the `<contexts>` XML element and everything inside. You also seem to be mixing source file names with assembly names. If your assembly name is `SportsStore.domain` then that explains why you get _file not found_ when you instruct EF to load `EFDbContext`.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the contexts from the XML. Now When I start my app, the error message Is gone, but no rows are printed. And can u explain for me what an Initializer is used for? What are they for?

Comment: @Bryan: Not surprisingly a database initializer is used to initialize a database. This is often used with migrations where you want to modify (migrate) the database schema when your context is modified. For more information please see [`IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323(v=vs.113).aspx) and in particular the classes mentioned in the documentation that implements this interface.

Comment: Thank you. Do u have any suggestions why the rows are not shown when I start my application?

Comment: @Bryan: No, I am not psychic and you have just shown some boilerplate code where the main problem was a bad configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I have always solved this issues in ASP.NET Scaffolding with VS using the following commando on the PM console (Package Manager Console)

```
PM> Update-Database  -Force
```

That should be work for you!